# How to disable windows application crash reporting?

Tags: php, windows, exec

I am trying to invoke external program (in my case IECapt.exe) in php function exec() on windows.

It works well most of the time, but when IECapt.exe crash, windows pop-up a crash prompt window,

and php script hangs there wait this prompt window closed, so how to disable such pop-up crash window?

because my php script need run as a daemon, and not expected paused when this happens.

how to make it just quit when crash?

thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Do you have access to the source code for IECapt, so you can make changes to it?

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/sysdm_advancd_exception_reporting.mspx?mfr=true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set an exception filter via [SetUnhandledExceptionFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680634(VS.85).aspx) that calls TerminateProcess.